# Isolation for a long distance industrial CAN + audio box

Tags: grounding, can, isolation, shield

I am working on an industrial control board + node network system. This system needs to be very robust, both for signal integrity as well as protection from transients.

The basic setup is shown here:

[image]

Since the Ethernet connection going to the server is fully isolated, I don't think there really is much to discuss there. Going from the control board to the IO board is a CAN bus and balanced audio line. These will either be on a separate cable, or on the same Cat6e cable.

All cables will be shielded, with the shield directly terminated to the enclosure/chassis. I have left the PCB ground and chassis unconnected in the image, as I would like suggestions on that as well. The plan would be to dedicate a single PCB layer for chassis ground. (Of course, if chassis gnd = digital gnd, then there will be multiple layers for them.)

For the following discussion, I will only show the CAN bus setup, as the audio will be fully isolated thanks to the transformers. It will also not require a common ground wire to equalize the grounds.

Option 1:

[image]

No isolation. Neither the CAN nor audio lines will have any isolation. To ensure that the common mode voltage stays within a safe range, CAN_GND = CONTROL_BOARD_DIG_GND = IO_BOARD_DIG_GND.

Option 2:

[image]

Full isolation on one side (let’s say the control board side for discussions sake.)

Option 3:

[image]

Full isolation on both sides.

For the isolation, assume that for the CAN, some sort of powered, digital isolator is used. For the audio, as stated above, a 1:1 transformer will be used.

My assumptions/thoughts:

1. Option 2/3 is an improvement over option 1, as it eliminates most ground loops. (There will still be a potential loop from chassis 1 -> shield -> chassis 2 -> earth -> chassis 1. Either capacitively from the chassis to earth, or if both metal boxes are mounted to a metal connection that is earth  grounded.)
2. Option 3 may be an improvement over 2 because any surges/transients that hit the cable will be limited to the CAN transceiver, since both sides are isolated.
3. If there was a 8kV strike on the cable, option one would potentially show that voltage on the digital ground for both boards. Unless it was fully clamped and protected, this would destroy pretty much everything on both boards. Option 2 would show the voltage on the IO board digital ground only. Option 3 should be fully protected. *Note: The CAN transceivers should survive in option 3, since the relative voltage between tx/rx and isolated transceiver ground would stay low, since all conductor would (or should) show the same 8kV.*
4. Whichever route I choose, I will still fully protect lines with TVS diodes.

Questions:

1. Are my assumptions correct for the most part?
2. If they are, then I will likely go with option 3. Should the chassis on both boards stay isolated from the digital ground?
3. If I go with option 3, should I use a safety cap to bridge the isolation gap? [How to use isolation to improve ESD, EFT and surge immunity in industrial systems](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt725/slyt725.pdf?ts=1656019067763&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) seems to think that I should.
4. Any other notes/thoughts that I am wrong or missing here?

Comment: Look what this chip does on page 18. I have used them for isolated 485 and page 18 describes how you add a safety cap although it's for noise reduction really: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm2582e_2587e.pdf

Comment: I think you have too many questions in one question. It would take a book about subject of grounding in a system to answer them, but what the whole system even is? For example, likely a server PC has chassis earthed and likely Ethernet connector metal shield is connected to chassis, and a shielded CAT cable connects shield to connector shell. So your device metal chassis will likely be earthed too. So depending on why you want galvanic isolation and where is a mystery, what problem there is that isolation solves? And usually shield is for shielding, not equalizing potential whics needs a wire.

Comment: Transformer isolated balanced audio doesn’t require a separate ground line with it.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for that. Interesting how they recommend just using an "embedded" cap instead. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bryan Whoops, you are indeed correct. I will make some edits to the post. Much appreciated. I do think that now makes option 3 a no-brainer, since both the audio and CAN will be of a similar setup.

Comment: @Justme Hm. I tried to include enough info in the post. I suppose I failed. Though, your specific points I do believe I answered all of them. For the system, can assume it's just two MCU's talking to each other, with some remote sensors. The isolation solves ground loops and helps with surges/transients. I'm not using shielding for equalizing potentials, that's what the third wire is for.

(Also, PC chassis are earthed because they have an internal AC/DC supply. It's for safety only. This would have an external AC/DC, making the safety concern null.)

Comment: Why use CAN if you only have two boards? Unless there are going to be more boards?

Comment: Option 3 is the lowest risk route and a no-brainer, if a little costlier but, sometimes you just have to bite the bullet, spend a few quid more and rest easy at night knowing you've done your best.

Comment: @bobflux Indeed, there will be future expansions to multi-node drops.

Comment: That's an important detail, because if you put the isolator only on the master side, all nodes will share a ground. But if you put it in the nodes, then the nodes can all have floating grounds.

Comment: @bobflux That's what I'm gathering now as well. If ALL nodes are using an isolated transceiver powered by their own isolated DC/DC supply, then I don't even need to send a common ground reference that all nodes tied their isolated supply to, correct? Just the two balanced comms lines.

Comment: EDIT to my above note: I don't know now, half the sources I find say that you still should have a common ground when all nodes are isolated. The others say they don't have to be..

Comment: @KyleHunter CAN bus (like RS485 or USB or any other differential bus) always needs a ground reference. Just look at any differential bus application notes. It will never work without common reference between transceivers. Unless for example both boxes have mains power supply which connects CAN grounds to earth, then CAN chips have same ground reference via mains earth wiring and are able to talk. Especially with isolated and floating supplies you need common referece. So you can have isolation but not the way you imagine.

Comment: @Justme Yes, that was my original assumption, and how I drew it in option three. The third wire ties the ground references together. There's just tons of info out there on datasheets and appnotes that states that you don't strictly need the third wire.

Comment: @KyleHunter Which appnotes and where? The appnotes I've read have always said the contrary, even RS485 specifications, and many buses that use it. They simply say they don't show or draw ground for simplicty but chips must share a reference. I don't think CAN is that different.

Comment: @Justme While not an appnote, here's a quick one I found (I have a ton of tabs I need to go through): https://ez.analog.com/interface-isolation/f/q-a/84965/isolated-can-with-adm3053-and-ground-wire . Application engineer for Analog. This also shows page 17, just two wire terminal block: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM3053.pdf

Comment: @KyleHunter It's not the first time an application engineer misunderstands the situation and says something wrong or irrelevant. Like he says CAN bus chip grounds must be within certain common mode voltage. So you don't need a ground between boxes if you somehow guarantee all chip grounds are within -7V to +12V each others, like they likey are in a car or building if chip grounds are earthed via power supply or bolted to same robot chassis. So share a ground. And the chip you linked has a bus side ground and again chip grounds (bus common mode) needs to be within -7V to +12V or it won't work.

Comment: @Justme Hah got it. Makes sense. I'm thinking yeah, to do what I showed for option three, but tie the control board isolated ground to its local PE ground. So then, all will be referenced to its PE, and since they're all isolated, there can't be any ground loops.

Comment: @Justme The problem with power supply grounds in industrial/automotive systems is that a lot of crap might flow through there. If you get spikes, surges and ground currents on the supply, you don't want to use that as reference for CAN, or you may get spurious error frames on the bus.

Comment: You say you will use shielding. If so the ESD will go through the shield/chassis and not the signals. The only danger is when connecting the parts for the first time or when the installer touches the signal pins of the cable with their fingers etc. And even then, modern transceivers are rated for 8kV contact/15kV air as per the toughest requirement of normal ESD standards. External TVS on the CAN lines shouldn't be necessary unless you need some higher level of protection still.

Answer (score 0):

> Any other notes/thoughts that I am wrong or missing here?

Answer: All your design Specs.

### Rule #1

1. All designs must have "SPECS" or a design specification before choosing an implementation.
2. All specs must be validated (DVT), documented, and revised/guaranteed for customers with process margins, including yours. This is part of a contract that you choose to warrant.
3. Choose from Industry standards before re-inventing the wheel, unless you know of specific exceptions.  Then compare different experts' advice/ IC datasheets and follow the common guides to achieve this.
4. Under the general guideline of EMI, ESD is a subset with well-defined standards such as the human body model, HBM of the fingertip (100 pF), and the Cart model.  There are also EM ingress standards for pulse, continuous (CW), and modulated carrier which may be coupled by L or C physical properties of all conductors and insulators in the network as well as a choice of isolation and ground (=0V).  Crosstalk is a parameter of choice for suppression levels. Often these are symmetrical with some emission spectrums by a shared filter.

[image] [ref](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adm2582e_2587e.pdf)

### added

[image]

> Questions:

1. Are my assumptions correct for the most part?
2. If they are, then I will likely go with option 3. Should the chassis on both boards stay isolated from the digital ground?
3. If I go with option 3, should I use a safety cap to bridge the isolation gap? How to use isolation to improve ESD, EFT and surge immunity in industrial systems seems to think that I should.
4. Any other notes/thoughts that I am wrong or missing here?

Opinions:

1. yes
2. Optional C=1nF RF cap like CAT5 terminations. or PE bonded to suppress SMPS floating CM noise. Verify with tests.
3. if protection diodes are faster than the arc surge Yes, if not maybe. It depends on layout and surge current paths, crosstalk or ground shift and slew rate in kV/ns.  Model using 10 nH/cm on wires.
4. See 1st answer.

If ESD is rated for an impulse <10 us @ 8kV and the device is rated for 4kV for the 60s and you want to improve choose a tougher spec like 8kV for 1s, then one must examine all sources of Breakdown voltage using a current limited low C tester, examine slew rate limiting filters to attenuate 8kV impulses with impedance matching and current limiting tradeoffs to clamp. however it is easier to limit current from crosstalk if floating but CM rejection of RF depends on cable quality for imbalance, kinks, and dB of isolation at RF spectrum from impulses is an additional task.

For example, a BIL-rated insulator for 200kV 1,10us impulse can easily break down at 50kV continuous AC or DC due to air contamination with %RH and surface creepage. This stress is unlikely for CANBUS environments but the ratios tell you about ionization delays and how greater impulses can be withstood. E.g. 8kV 100 pF ESD.

Comment: Erm, I suppose thanks for that? Didn't really help much, or any. When the customer doesn't require meeting a specific standard for their application, finding one for the sake of finding one doesn't really solve that much. Typically they want it to be resilient "enough" to be reliable. At least that's how most contract design work, well works.

Also, even with a specific standard to design towards, most of these questions would still be valid, as the standard won't lay it out completely for something like this.

Comment: When your customer doesn't know any better , you should and make a guestimate and choose a std. So follow the rules in this datasheet or choose another, If you cannot , then I cannot help, nor anyone. I used to write datasheet specs from customer's fuzzy light descriptions and even "Paper Napkin" specs from Lucent.  For DIY it doesn't matter and then produce something I verified to same, even with dry ice and a heater in a picnic box if you don't have a Tenney Chamber

Comment: OK, for discussions sake, I choose to follow the datasheet you shared. Now, I still need to answer my above questions... Lol, that's what I was getting at, having a standard really doesn't help things for what I need.

Comment: I once had a Power One 180W that failed miserably for Hipot after the process control was slack moving from SD to Mex. They tested with DC floating. I tested with DC PE bonded. This is more stressful on the highest impedance insulator on the AC side and caused breakdown arcs and destructive failures. I later added a 1M current limiting R to my HiPot test and disqualified them until all issues fixed.  Their QA Mgr was in disbelief. We used 1k units /mo . end customer was AVAYA , my design.

Comment: Thanks for your edits, very helpful! With that in mind, and seeing https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla486a/slla486a.pdf?ts=1656184482024& (Number 7) and https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-770.pdf (Page 3.SYSTEM ISOLATION OVERVIEW), I think the plan may be to use option 3, but tie the isolated ground on the control board to PE, so all will be referenced to that single ground point. Still fuzzy on what the chassis would be, but at least making progress!

Comment: To assess sample environmental noise, take a typical long wire pair terminated and measure noise on a DSO terminated 50 Ohms then do all the load dump tests. Cap discharge into parallel wires, or use the expensive testers.  For E-field use a single wire terminated into 50 R and repeat.